# Why is my next js app is failing to deploy to vercel, because of @next/swc-darwin-arm64?

Tags: next.js, deployment, node-modules, vercel

I just tried to deploy my next js app to vercel and I received this build error:

```
error @next/swc-darwin-arm64@13.2.4: The platform "linux" is incompatible with this module.
error @next/swc-darwin-arm64@13.2.4: The CPU architecture "x64" is incompatible with this module.
error Found incompatible module.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 1
BUILD_FAILED: Command "yarn install" exited with 1
```

First of all - what is `@next/swc-darwin-arm64`, it sounds like it's a part of next js?

If its internal next js module, does that mean that next js has failed itself?

Is its something that I have to report to vercel and how can I fix this and simply deploy my app?

Answer (score 0):

In your `package.json` you likely installed the `@next/swc-darwin-arm64` library, which works on your local machine (since it has `{"os":"darwin","arch":"arm64"}`) but not on your deployed environment, which uses linux.

You'll need to ensure this library is removed before deployment.